# Rounding mistake after editing a product

Tags: rounding

if I want to add a new Product (sale price 39,99) I can set the price like this: 33,60504201680672 (without tax).

The price in the shop is now shown correct: 39,99.

If I edit then the product, the price is in backend 33,61 and in frontend 40,00.

I already set the rounding decimal place in Store.php from 2 up to 4.

The Magento version is 1.7.0.2.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you try this [free community extension](https://github.com/therouv/Magento-BetterPriceRounding)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980164/magento-how-do-i-set-the-product-price-to-4-decimal-places

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php

```
return number_format($value, 4, null, '');
```

Comment: Yep, the already mentioned extension solves this issue. And you should better use the extension and not edit the core file. Will add it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The free extension [`Itabs_BetterPriceRounding`](https://github.com/therouv/Magento-BetterPriceRounding) solves nearly all rounding issues. It changes the rounding precision from 2 to 4 digits in all places used by Magento. It should also solve your problem.